# Use percentage of width in non-width properties

Tags: css

I can use the CSS property `top:60vw` to position the top of an element at 60% of the *views* width. Is there a similar method to position the element at 60% of a *containers* width without referencing the view width?

I need CSS, not SCSS methods.

Comment: No, there's no way to do that without using javascript.

Answer (score -2):

if you use position relative it has to work.

```css
position: relative;
top: 60vw;
```

``

Comment: This solution seems to reference the view width (see units) and does not answer the original question.